# How to get when Local Notification is fired on iOS 10+

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin.iOS and I know that **ReceivedLocalNotification** is deprecated on iOS 10+

So I implemented:

```
 UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();
```

Which leads to following:

```
public class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate { 

    public UserNotificationCenterDelegate() { } 

    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler) 
    {
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert); 
    } 

    public override void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I am using iOS 10/ iOS 11 and the Local Notification fires in background but I am not able to get the event.

Is this even possible to get the event when Local Notification is fired without the user interacting with it?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45315483/ios-open-page-from-local-notification/45319426#45319426

Comment: How does it help? Push notification stops at WillPresentNotification when appears, but Local Notification is not

Comment: What do you really want? get `DidReceiveNotificationResponse` or `WillPresentNotification` without any user interaction?